# Non-stretching health bar?

Tags: unity, unity-ui

Here's what I want:

[image: Loading bar - progress is a grass image that does not scale but appears as the "slider" passes it without separate images.]

Here's what I got:

[image: An image of grass that stretches with health bar fill.]

What is this procedural image unmasking called? Popcap didn't do image-splitting (source images below), but I feel like I'm missing the obvious here.

(Source images)

[image: game grass image]
[image: Game dirt image]

I'm currently using a world-space canvas, an empty game object with a slider component, and two UI image components.

[image: Unit scene hierarchy]

I'm giving Unity a fresh shot after some bad experiences with it previously, so I apologize for my newbie-ishness.

Comment: Maybe using a [Mask](https://docs.huihoo.com/unity/5.4/Documentation/en/Manual/script-Mask.html) as the fill element of the progress bar.

Comment: I hate when expert developers like Blizzard get this wrong on their loading bars.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since *Canvas > LoadBar > Grass* has an `Image` Component, all you need to do is set the **Image Type** property to "Filled". Then, the Inspector will expose new properties: **Fill Method** and **Fill Origin**. Set the former to "Horizontal" and the latter to "Left". Use the **Fill Amount** property to change the fill percentage of your *Grass* `Image`. [Change this value programmatically](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.UI.Image.html#UnityEngine_UI_Image_fillAmount), passing the loading percentage in the \$[0, 1]\$ interval.

Comment: Aced it! Thank you! 

Note: You also have to set the `Fill Method` and `Fill Origin` on the Image component to your liking to get this one to work.